# WordPress, pass variable from page.php to header.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I try to create a theme in WordPress, and allow the user for some Page Templates, to load either a Slide-show in the header or to display the title.

Lets say, I have a template name called, Portfolio and another page template called Portfolio with Slide-show In Head.

Can I from within the `portfolio.php` and `portfolio-with-slide.php` to send variables in the `header.php` in order to decide what to display, or have I to create a second header for the second option and load the one need it into the template file with `get_header('title')` and `get_header('slide')`

What is the best approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally use the second option - create a second header for the second option and load the one need it into the template file with `get_header('title')` and `get_header('slide')`.
This is the best approach in terms of code maintainability.

Comment: This is the way I have finally follow. Kind regards @budiony

Answer (score 2):

A proper solution is to write a filter to replace the title:

```
function this_is_the_title_now( $title ) {
    // can return un-altered $title or can use fancy logic here
    return( "This is the new title." );
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'this_is_the_title_now', 10, 2 );
```

This can be put into functions.php of your theme, or in page-whatever.php.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make it crear, I don't like to change the title into the head section. I like to change the title into the header section of my web site. I mean the title next to the top menu. This section in my template located into the header.php

Comment: this one is the best answer. hook (action) and filter is your best friend on WordPress :)

Answer (score 1):

since wordpress 5.5 `get_header` has `$args` parameter ready to use:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/

You can just put your arguments into `get_header` like this:

`get_header( 'yourheadername', [ 'header_arg' => 'XYZ' ] );` (if you're using customized header.php file, in this case would it be: `header-yourheadername.php`)

or for default header.php file:

`get_header( null, [ 'header_arg' => 'XYZ' ] );`

then inside your header file you can use:

`<?php echo $args['header_arg']; ?>`
inside `if` or whatever you want :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_query_var` to send variables to your header.php file, or any template part file.

For example, in your Portfolio Slideshow template (`portfolio-with-slide.php`) file:

```
//portfolio-with-slide.php 
set_query_var('includeSlideshow', true);
```

Then in your `header.php` file (or a template part file):

```
//Header.php
$slideshowHeader = get_query_var('includeSlideShow');
//If variable exists and is boolean true
if($slideshowHeader !== null && $slideshowHeader === true) {
  //code to include slideshow in header
}
```